# Three.js - space warp

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'd like to code something like this with webgl & three.js: [image: space warp]

Where to start with it? I mean besides reading the documentation ofc. I have no idea what kind of algorithm can do this...

Comment: look at tunnel effects in webgl and shaders

Comment: what did you try so far? SO's guidelines suggest questions this vague and open should be voted for closing

Comment: @gman It's hard to do anything if you have no idea where to start. Ofc. vote close if you want.

Comment: @Careen Thanks, I have found something similar with this info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451376/how-to-implement-this-tunnel-like-animation-in-webgl Probably a good place to start.