# Glsl mod vs Hlsl fmod

Tags: math, opengl, directx, glsl, hlsl

I've implemented the spiral GLSL shader described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4638317/2877364) in HLSL, but the results are not the same.  I think it's because of the `mod` function in GLSL that I've translated to `fmod` in HLSL.  I suspect that this problem only happens when we have negative numbers in the input of the `fmod` function.

I've tried replacing the call to `mod` by a call to a function that I've made which does what is described in the [GLSL documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/mod.xml) and it works:

> `mod` returns the value of `x` modulo `y`. This is computed as `x - y * floor(x/y)`.

The working code I use instead of `fmod` is:

```
float mod(float x, float y)
{
  return x - y * floor(x/y)
}
```

By contrast to GLSL `mod`, [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509601(v=vs.85).aspx) the HLSL `fmod` function does this:

> The floating-point remainder is calculated such that `x = i * y + f`, where `i` is an integer, `f` has the same sign as `x`, and the absolute value of `f` is less than the absolute value of `y`.

I've used [an HLSL to GLSL converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hlsl2glsl), and the `fmod` function is translated as `mod`.  However, I don't know if I can assume that `mod` translates to `fmod`.

#### Questions

1. What are the differences between GLSL `mod` and HLSL`fmod`?
2. How can I translate MSDN's cryptic description of `fmod` to a pseudo-code implementation?

#### GLSL Shader

```
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec2 aspect;

void main( void ) {
  vec2 position = -aspect.xy + 2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy * aspect.xy;
  float angle = 0.0 ;
  float radius = length(position) ;
  if (position.x != 0.0 && position.y != 0.0){
    angle = degrees(atan(position.y,position.x)) ;
  }
  float amod = mod(angle+30.0*time-120.0*log(radius), 30.0) ;
  if (amod<15.0){
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
  } else{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );                    
  }
}
```

#### HLSL Shader

```
struct Psl_VertexShaderInput
{
    float3 pos : POSITION;
};

struct Psl_VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 pos : POSITION;

};

struct Psl_PixelShaderOutput
{
    float4 Output0 : COLOR0;
};

float3 psl_positionOffset;
float2 psl_dimension;

Psl_VertexShaderOutput Psl_VertexShaderFunction(Psl_VertexShaderInput psl_input)
{
    Psl_VertexShaderOutput psl_output = (Psl_VertexShaderOutput)0;

    psl_output.pos = float4(psl_input.pos + psl_positionOffset, 1);


    return psl_output;
}

float time : TIME;
float2 resolution : DIMENSION;


Psl_PixelShaderOutput Psl_PixelShaderFunction(float2 pos : VPOS)
{
    Psl_PixelShaderOutput psl_output = (Psl_PixelShaderOutput)0;

    float2 aspect = float2(resolution.x / resolution.y, 1.0);
    float2 position = -aspect.xy + 2.0 * pos.xy / resolution.xy * aspect.xy;
    float angle = 0.0;
    float radius = length(position);
    if (position.x != 0.0 && position.y != 0.0)
    {
        angle = degrees(atan2(position.y, position.x));
    }
    float amod = fmod((angle + 30.0 * time - 120.0 * log(radius)), 30.0);
    if (amod < 15.0)
    {
        psl_output.Output0 = float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        return psl_output;
    }

    else
    {
        psl_output.Output0 = float4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        return psl_output;
    }

}

technique Default
{
    pass P0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 Psl_VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 Psl_PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can use % for mod in HLSL.

Comment: yes I tried but % gives exactly the same problem. The spiral is not correctly represented. 1/4 of it is cut

Comment: It would be helpful to see both shaders so that we can compare them.

Comment: Okey you are right. I'm going to provide them

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you've noted, they're different.  The GLSL `mod` will always have the same sign as `y` rather than `x`.  Otherwise it's the same -- a value `f` such that `x = i*y + f` where `i` is an integer and `|f| < |y|`.  If you're trying to make a repeating pattern of some kind, the GLSL `mod` is generally what you want.

For comparison, the HLSL `fmod` is equivalent to `x - y * trunc(x/y)`.  They're the same when `x/y` is positive, different when `x/y` is negative.